# web service URL to be more configurable in the binary file .ipa/.apk. In order to reduce dependency of re-compiling the app

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Is there any possible ways that we can configure URL on app so that if URL has changed then no need to recompile the code and generate the binary file again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the feasibility.
You have to make one URL configuration file which is on the server side. Whenever APP is installed first time **URL config file** need to download from the server. The file should be property file with **key=value** pair. **when ever URLs are changed only need to update the file version**. When file version is updated you have to only download file and use it.
For reference link is below.
[Here is link](http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/dynamic-handling-of-stringstext-for-mobile-apps-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should build configuration service on server side if possible on another than u want to communicate or have webservices deployed. Depending what data u need u can easily handle:

url changes - hosts or versions of web services
drop-out of server to connect other server or to inform user
what u imagine - data filters - security check - over clients version e.g.